# how to read text file from django server using ajax?

Tags: ajax, django

I wanna know how to read text file from django server  using ajax? or something else.

I searched about using XMLHttpRequest and It worked when I tryed to get django template html file. but I couldn't get other text file outside of templates directory. how can I send content of requested file in veiw.py ?? 
I think I cant use render_to_response()..

I need your help:(

Answer (score 0):

Simething like this in your url:

```
url(r'^static/mymedia/'       , 'myproject.views.get_file'),
```

Something like this in your views:

```
def get_file(request):
  current_directory='/home/arpit/myproject/'
  f=open(current_directory+request.path)
  return HttpResponse(f.read(),mimetype='text/plain')
```

Comment: thanks. i  didnt know to use f.read(). then, how can I do f.close()?

Comment: r=f.read()  
f.close()  
return HttpResponse(r,mimetype='text/plain')